# Are there certain sounds that only occur when a unit is born? Or is it random?

Tags: starcraft-2

I noticed, that a queen always makes the same sound, when it's born. Is it the same with all units?

The first sound in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nPdrnnfnnQ) is the queen birth sound (the video is continuing with all other sounds a queen can produce)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

> I noticed, that a queen always makes the same sound, when it's born.
>   Is it the same with all units?

All Zerg units, like all other StarCraft 2 units, have their own and only 1 "creation" / "spawn" sound.

Heres a list with all the units sounds:
http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/StarCraft_II_unit_quotations

EDIT: Note that Zerg units arent exactly speech, but rather a beast like sound. Its always the same though.

Comment: those page doesen't show any birthing sounds at all

Comment: @rubo77 I assume that by birthing sounds, you meen when a unit is trained? Anyway. The reason why there are no Zerg "Trained / Birth" sound is because it cannot be spelled, as its just noise, and not anything spoken. I guess a Zergling sound would something like "Reeaaahhshshsss" :) But even with Zerg spawn sounds, its always the same sound.

Comment: But a soundfile would show us, how it sounds. I expect to **hear** the sound don't read it ;) (maybe my broken english doesen't use the right words in the question? )

Comment: You ask "Are there certain sounds that only occur when a unit is born? Or is it random?" And "I noticed, that a queen always makes the same sound, when it's born. Is it the same with all units?" Its a streight up question. In your other question, you yourself linked to the sounds. Your question does not say anything about a sound file besides a link to a Zerg Queen.

Comment: Ah OK, so it is the same birth sound each time. Is there a collection somewhere how these birthsounds are? I only found the [playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?feature=edit_ok&list=PLw2rQQXjRQExvInqZ2vD_M5-MwLkIfAdK) with all sounds they make, but no Idea which are the specific birthsounds in those videos. (Maybe it is the first sound in each video?)

Comment: You can try to play as zerg against a very easy computer. Try to make every unit again and again. And you will see that every spawning sound is the same. By time you will learn what it sounds like.

Answer (score -1):

It is not random. You hear the same sound every time a unit hatches from the egg.

Here you can hear [each Zerg unit hatching from the egg](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLw2rQQXjRQEyf_ItzhB6gdQtlghGa-RQn).

I checked some, and it seems every first sound in each video of [this playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?feature=edit_ok&list=PLw2rQQXjRQExvInqZ2vD_M5-MwLkIfAdK) is the sound you hear when that unit is born